# Align checkboxes having 100% width without labels to the left

Tags: html, css

I want to use checkboxes having a width of 100% of container to the left but I don't find a solution how to do that.

That's my HTML code:

```css
.checkboxes {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 400px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" id="scales" name="scales">
  <input type="checkbox" id="horns" name="horns">
</div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D; By running the code snippet you can see the result at the bottom/right, that shows the checkboxes centered. I think it's clear that I want to align them left in my question, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `margin: 0 auto; width: 100%;` from `input[type="checkbox"]`. Having auto on the sides places the box in the middle.

Having display block will make sure it's on its own line

Comment: Thanks, removing `margin: 0 auto;` don't resolve the problem, the checkboxes are always centered.

Comment: @Bizboss Sorry! Remove width: 100% too

Comment: Thank you, but that don't let the right space of the checkboxes cliquable... I want the whole width to be clickable, that's why I have tried width 100%

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why you would want this? The checkbox itself is restricted to the box it currently is. You can use labels to create a clickable space next to the checkbox but this is changing its default behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @Taylor Stocks, I have used the lablels